# Stored procedure to replace certain variables in string

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm working on a stored procedure that will accept a string and return a new string of text. Input parameters are `@OrderId` and `@OrderText` which is a string with dollar sign enclosed variables like so... `$Order Name$ sent to $Customer$`

The valid variables are in a `Variables` table (values such as Order Name, Customer, a total of 25 of them which should remain fairly static). Variables can only be used once in the string.

The stored procedure needs to return the string but with the variables replaced with their respective values.

Example1

Input: `123, $Order Name$ sent to $Customer$`

Returns: `Toolkit sent to StackCustomer Inc.`

Example2

Input: `456, $Customer$ requests $delivery method$ for $order type$`

Returns: `ABC Inc requests fast shipping for pallet orders.`

Each of the variables can be retrieved using a function.

```
    DECLARE @OrderId int = 123
    DECLARE @InputText VARCHAR(500) = '$Order Name$ sent to $Customer$'
    select 
     @InputText = case when @InputText like '%$order name$%' 
             then replace(@InputText, '$Order Name$', getOrderName(id) else '' end,
     @InputText = case when @InputText like '%$customer$' 
             then replace(@InputText, '$Customer$', getCustomer(id) else '' end
      -- repeat 25 times
```

Is there a better way? My main concern is maintainability - if a variable is added, renamed, or removed, this stored proc will need to be changed (although I'm told it would only happen a couple times a year, if that). Would dynamic sql be able to help in this case?

Comment: What exactly are you doing in the functions?  Maybe post a sample of that code.  Also, is the input string format always the same or do you have control over the format of this as well?

Comment: Since TSQL is a poor language for text manipulation in general, I think a better way would be to do this in an application using an existing templating toolkit of some kind.

Comment: @Nate no control over the format of the input string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would create a keywords table to maintain it. something like this

```
CREATE TABLE [keywords] (
  key_value VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  function_value VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
  )
INSERT INTO [keywords]
VALUES
('$Customer$','getCustomer(id)'),
('$Order Name$' ,'getOrderName(id)'),
('$order type$','getOrderType(id)')
```

Then use dynamic sql create REPLACE SQL

```
DECLARE @OrderId int = 123
DECLARE @InputText VARCHAR(500) = '$Order Name$ sent to $Customer$'

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000) = 'SELECT '

SELECT 
  @sql = @sql + 
  ' @InputText = replace(@InputText, ''' + key_value + ''', ' + function_value + ')'
    + ' ,'
FROM keywords
WHERE  @InputText LIKE '%' + key_value + '%'


SELECT @sql = LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql) -1)
PRINT @sql

EXEC(@sql)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3adc3/17)

Answer (score 0):

I am not really getting why you need to do tokenization if you are going to use input variables for the procedure.

There are token templates already available for SQL Management Studio in the form of:

```
<(tokenName),(datatype),(defaultvalue)>
```

You can get their data filled directly with SQL Managment Studio with CTRL + SHIFT + M, or with ALT > Q > S in 2012, or by text finding their values in an environment.

If you are trying to put in an input to be accessed by an outside developing platform that changes the strings like ADO.NET or the Entity Framework in C#/VB.NET I still am not getting why you would not just make more input variables.

You could do this quite easily:

```
Declare @OrderPlace varchar(128), @Customer varchar(64), @StringCombine varchar(512);

Select 
   @OrderPlace = 'Place I am at'
,  @Customer = 'Mr Customer';

Select @StringCombine = @Customer + ' order at ' + @OrderPlace
```

Then if a different language accessed your SQL server procedure it would just have to put in two parameters @Customer and @OrderPlace.  You could even set @StringCombine to be an output variable.  This is much more preferable then text replacing characters and then running a string.  This could be able for SQL injection attacks potentially so santizing your inputs is a big part of returning data, especially if you are altering something for SQL to run before it is ran.

You mentioned maintainability and this is much more robust because if I change the logic to the proc but DO NOT change the variables names, I did not have to change anything else.  If I have to change an ADO.NET or other library for references and then SQL code, that is lot more work.  Generally when working with tokens I strive for reuse of code where one part of it can go down and only hurt that part of it, not take the whole thing down.